# The uncertainty principle and magnetic bar

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

As far as I know, the magnetic properties of a bar magnet is due to the alignment of electronic spins of all the atoms. According to the uncertainty principle the electronic spin is randomly up or down. So, why a bar magnet has certain poles while it may be expected its poles interchange? I appreciate any help about my misunderstanding.

Comment: "According to the uncertainty principle the electronic spin is randomly up or down". This is an oversimplification. Upon measurement an individual spin may be either up or down, but that does not imply the probabilities for up and down are equal, nor does it imply anything about the expected value for a large ensemble of spins, like in a magnet.

Comment: [MAGNETS: How Do They Work?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hFAOXdXZ5TM)

Comment: You are right about the ensemble but in the crystalline structures it is expected that all the atoms in unit cells behave identically.

Answer (score 1):

The spin of an individual isolated electron may vary randomly. However, electrons in the atoms of a magnet are *not* isolated. And one of the important lessons from quantum dynamics is that the behaviour of a group of particles may be very different from the behaviour of the individual particles on their own.

For a start, electrons in atoms tend to group together in pairs such that the two electrons in each pair have opposite spin alignment - this state is energetically favourable. This is why most materials have no (or, at least a very small) overall magnetic field. In a few materials, where there are unpaired electrons, these electrons will align their spins with an external magnetic field. And in an even smaller number of materials, the unpaired electrons will retain this alignment even when the external magnetic field is removed - these materials are [ferromagnetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferromagnetism), and can be used to create permanent magnets.

Comment: As I said in my last comment in the crystalline structures we may not expect the random change of magnetism from one unit cell to another!

Comment: That depends! Chemists know when to expect diamagnetism and paramagnetism from electron structure of the crystal atoms for instance. In iron we have neither, we have ferromagnetism. But you are correct that these phenomena can not be inferred only from the crystal structure, you also need to know what atoms make up the crystal, and what electron structure these atoms have.